# Can I know the script that repeats mouse clicks in a specific location?

Tags: lua

Can I know the script that repeats mouse clicks in a specific location?

MoveMouseTo(62487,39895)
PressMouseButton(1)
sleep(1)

I am a beginner. Results value created by searching, but an error occurs.

MoveMouseTo(62487,39895)
PressMouseButton(1)
sleep(1)

Answer (score 0):

It repeats mouse click while mouse button 5 is pressed

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   --OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
      repeat
         MoveMouseTo(62487,39895) 
         Sleep(50)
         PressMouseButton(1) 
         Sleep(50)
         ReleaseMouseButton(1) 
         Sleep(50)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
   end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep clicking at 1-second intervals?

Comment: Replace the last `Sleep(50)` with `Sleep(900)`